# SQL Server Extract overlapping date ranges (return dates that cross other dates)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

How would I go about extracting the overlapping dates from the following table?

```
ID  Name        StartDate   EndDate     Type
==============================================================
1   John Smith  01/01/2014  31/01/2014  A
2   John Smith  20/01/2014  20/02/2014  B
3   John Smith  01/03/2014  28/03/2014  A
4   John Smith  18/03/2014  24/03/2014  B
5   John Smith  01/07/2014  31/07/2014  A
6   John Smith  15/07/2014  31/07/2014  B
7   John Smith  25/07/2014  25/08/2014  C
```

Based on the first example for John Smith, the dates 01/01/2014 to 31/01/2014 overlap with 20/01/2014 to 20/02/2014, so I am expecting just overlapping period back which is 20/01/2014 to 31/01/2014.

The final result would be:

```
ID  Name        StartDate   EndDate
==================================================
8   John Smith  20/01/2014  31/01/2014
9   John Smith  18/03/2014  24/03/2014
10  John Smith  15/07/2014  31/07/2014
11  John Smith  25/07/2014  31/07/2014
```

HELP REQUIRED 10 August 2014

In addition to the above request, I am looking for help or guidance on how to get the following results which should include the dates that overlap and the dates that don't. The ID column is irrelevant.

```
ID  Name        StartDate   EndDate     Type
==================================================
1   John Smith  01/01/2014  19/01/2014  A
8   John Smith  20/01/2014  31/01/2014  AB
2   John Smith  01/02/2014  20/02/2014  B
3   John Smith  01/03/2014  17/03/2014  A
9   John Smith  18/03/2014  24/03/2014  AB
3   John Smith  25/03/2014  28/03/2014  A
5   John Smith  01/07/2014  14/07/2014  A
10  John Smith  15/07/2014  31/07/2014  AB
11  John Smith  25/07/2014  31/07/2014  ABC
7   John Smith  01/08/2014  25/08/2014  C
```

Although the following image is not an exact reflection of the above, for illustration purposes, I am interested in seeing the dates that overlap (red) and the dates that don't (sky blue) in the same result set.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/11lnO.jpg

Comment: Can't you just use BETWEEN, and put the date ranges in there?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just overlapping periods, you can get this with a self join.  Do note that the results might be redundant if more than two periods overlap on certain dates.

```
select ft.name,
       (case when max(ft.startdate) > max(ft2.startdate) then max(ft.startdate)
             else max(ft2.startdate)
        end) as startdate,
       (case when min(ft.enddate) > min(ft2.enddate) then min(ft.enddate)
             else min(ft2.enddate)
        end) as enddate
from followingtable ft join
     followingtable ft2
     on ft.name = ft2.name and
        ft.id < ft2.id and
        ft.startdate <= ft2.enddate and
        ft.enddate > ft2.startdate
group by ft.name, ft.id, ft2.id;
```

This doesn't assign the `id`s.  You can do that with `row_number()` and an offset.